# I have a problem in a code which should find number of occurrence of a sub string in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

In the code below i want to find number of occurrence of a sub string in a string and the index of occurrence of that sub string.
so i made a while loop which if a same character found increment i and j,then if i % length of sub string entered count is incremented.so when i run it the program does not terminate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 256
int main()
{
    char line[MAX];
    char word[MAX];
    int l , w ;
    int i=0, j=0 ,count=0 ;
    fgets(line , MAX,stdin);
    fgets(word,MAX,stdin);
    l = strlen(line);
    w = strlen(word);
    while(i < l){
        if((line[i]==word[j])){
            i++ ;
            j++ ;
        }
        if( (i+1) % (w-1) == 0){
            printf("Occurrence at index %d",(i-w+2));

            count++ ;
        }
    }
    printf("Total number of occurrences = %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 is not i   incremented in the first if statement?

Comment: re. the algorithm itself, assuming you specifically want to do it yourself instead of using `strstr`: consider `word` = `"aab"` and `line` = `"aaab"`, then the correct match starts from the second `a`. Go through the steps yourself and see why what you are trying here won't work, even if you fix the missing iteration of `i` and reset of `j` on mismatch.

Comment: Further reading, for example: [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for your while loop is `i < l`. You do not modify `l` in the loop. The only place where you do increment `i` is

```
    if((line[i]==word[j])){
        i++ ;
        j++ ;
    }
```

If you ever hit an iteration where `line[i] != word[j]` then the while loop will never stop, because outside of that `if` you never modify `i`,`j` or `l`.

PS: I was lured here by a C++ tag. As it now turned out that the code is C, I cannot really tell you what would be the best way to fix it, but I am almost certain that also in C you don't have to invent a wheel to find substrings in a string.